# "High Risk Behavior" mark on Google Play

Tags: react-native, google-play

I've got a situation here and could really use your input. We've been working on a bunch of apps using React Native. They're all different in what they offer but share a lot of the same code underneath. We made sure they're secure and don't grab any personal data from users.
But here's the kicker - when we tried to get them up on Google Play, not only did they reject all our apps, but they also slammed our account shut for "High Risk Behavior." Totally didn't see that coming and we're scratching our heads over here.
Has anyone else been through something like this? Like, if you've tried to publish several apps that are kind of similar, did you hit any snags? What's the deal with Google thinking they're risky?
Would love to hear if you've got any stories or tips on dealing with this. We're just trying to figure out what went wrong and how to fix it.
Thanks a bunch for any help you can toss our way!

I tried to communicate with them but it was no use. So now I'd like to know if there any cases like mine.

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to Stackoverflow James!.

We can't really help without some information.
Which user permissions your app uses?
Usually they're pretty clear about these issues when it happens, you didn't receive any e-mail about it?

Append the "permissions" part of your `androidManifest.xml` so we can see how it is set-up

Make sure to read: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: James Keur, Have you launched all the app by the same account or used different account to launch each app?

Comment: I've used two different accounts to upload the app